# Cisco 1811 router - How to open port 80/port forwarding

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, console

I've set up an IIS server on windows server 2012 r2, but I cant access it from outside the LAN using the external IP. When I check port 80 on yougetsignal.com is says that port 80 is closed. I have been looking on the cisco documentation for how to do this, but it seems really complicated. First I need to open up a Global Configuration Console, and I need to connect to it using a serial cable? Im at work so I dont want to mess anything up. Can anyone describe this process for me please?

Answer (score 1):

1. Download [putty](http://www.putty%20org)
2. Connect to your router using the console cable ( the serial cable with
   other end RJ45)
3. Open putty, select Serial, click OPEN
4. You should now be in User Executive Mode. Type `enable`  to enter Privileged Mode
5. To access Global Configuration Mode from Privileged Mode, type
   `configure terminal`
6. Now you need to configure Port forwarding. Do the following steps

(i) enter the configuration terminal of the interface connected to your network (your inside interface)

```
)#interface "name-of-the-private-interface"
-if)#ip nat inside
-if)#exit
```

NOTE: type without quotes ( " " )

(ii) enter the configuration terminal of the interface connected to ISP (your outside interface)

```
)#interface "name-of-the-public-interface"
-if)#ip nat outside
-if)#exit
```

NOTE: type without quotes ( " " )

(iii) type command for port forwarding over port 80

```
)# ip nat inside source static tcp "ip of server" 80 interface "outside interface name" 80
```

NOTE: type without quotes ( " " )

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the nat is configured and your users are able to connect to the internet. 
Means the "ip nat inside" and "ip nat outside" are configured on your internal and external interface respectively.

And assuming you server IP address is 192.168.1.10 and you external interface (facing the Internet) is fe0/1 (FastEthernet 0/1), the command would be:

> ip nat source static tcp 192.168.1.10 80 interface fe0/1 80